# Why is el undefined and $el defined for this Backbone View?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am confused about why '''el''' is undefined here, and $el is defined.

[image: undefined el]

The background is en experiment with CoffeeScript as follows:

```
class FastTodo.Views.AddTodoItem extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['todo_items/add_item']

  el: $('#main')

  render: ->
    console.log("render")
    console.log($("#main"))
    console.log(@el)
    console.log(@)
    $(@el).html @template

  initialize: ->
    @render()
```

How can I render the view in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try rewriting the element declaration to `el: '#main'`

I think that should work well for you.

By the way, according to your console log the jQuery element ($el) is empty as well. You must be declaring the view before the markup has been fully loaded. By giving `el` the selector for the elements you make sure it will be fetched only when the document is ready (loaded).

Comment: thanks, indeed el: 'main' works, and it's also mentioned in the docs: http://backbonejs.org/#View-el - however, evt. someone knows why in some code you'll see a el: $('#main') form ?

Comment: imo it's a mistake, unless used with the `setElement` method

Comment: `el: $('#main')` works fine as long as the element `#main` exists in the DOM before your class is defined.

Comment: thanks, that would make sense indeed, still, in the experiment I was doing, I had:  $(document).ready ->
  FastTodo.initialize()  wrapping the view